# How to recognize a geometric sequence while solving by unfolding?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I have a problem with how this is written as a geometric sequence. I got this screenshot from my math book. $r$ should be $2$ and $a$ should be $1$.

$$S = \frac{1 - 2^{n-1}}{1 - 2}$$

How did they come up with $n$ as the power of $2$? And why is the sum being written backwards?
\begin{align*}
a_n & = 5 + 5(2) + 5(2^2) + 5(2^3) + \cdots + 5(2^{n - 1}) + 2^na_0\\
    & = 5(1 + 2 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^{n - 1}) + 2^n(2)\\
    & = 5 \frac{2^n - 1}{2 - 1} + 2(2^n)
\end{align*}

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your question rather than posting an image since images cannot be searched and users with screen readers may not be able to read them.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The geometric series to which the formula is being applied is $5 + 5(2) + 5(2^2) + 5(2^3) + \cdots + 5(2^{n - 1})$.  The final term is based on information that you did not include in your question.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I get that. Read my question please. How did they get 2^n instead of 2^(n-1)? And why is it 2-1 instead of 1-2 in the denominator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric sequence with initial term $a_1$ and common ratio $r$ is
$$S = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_1r^{k - 1} = a_1 + a_1r + a_1r^2 + \cdots + a_1r^{n - 1} \tag{1}$$
If we multiply this sum by $r$, we obtain
$$rS = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_1r^k = a_1r + a_1r^2 + a_1r^3 + \cdots + a_1r^n \tag{2}$$
Subtracting equation 2 from equation 1 yields
\begin{alignat*}{6}
S - rS & = a_1 & + a_1r & + a_1r^2 & + \cdots & + a_1r^{n - 1} & \\
       & =     & - a_1r & - a_1r^2 & - \cdots & - a_1r^{n - 1} & - a_1r^n\\ \hline
S(1 - r) & = a_1 & & & & & - a_1r^n 
\end{alignat*}
If $r \neq 1$, we may divide by $1 - r$ to obtain the formula for a geometric series
$$S = \frac{a_1 - a_1r^n}{1 - r} = a_1\frac{1 - r^n}{1 - r} \tag{3}$$
In your problem, the geometric series is
$$5 + 5(2) + 5(2^2) + 5(2^3) + \cdots + 5(2^{n - 1}) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} 5(2^{k - 1})$$
so $a_1 = 5$ and $r = 2$.  Using the formula in equation 3, we obtain
$$S = 5 + 5(2) + 5(2^2) + 5(2^3) + \cdots + 5(2^{n - 1}) = 5 \cdot \frac{1 - 2^n}{1 - 2}$$
If we multiply the numerator and denominator of the fraction
$$\frac{1 - 2^n}{1 - 2}$$
by $-1$, we obtain
$$\frac{1 - 2^n}{1 - 2} \cdot \frac{-1}{-1} = \frac{-1 + 2^n}{-1 + 2} = \frac{2^n - 1}{2 - 1}$$
Therefore,
$$S = 5 + 5(2) + 5(2^2) + 5(2^3) + \cdots + 5(2^{n - 1}) =  5 \cdot \frac{1 - 2^n}{1 - 2} = 5 \cdot \frac{2^n - 1}{2 - 1}$$
as the author claims.

Comment: We are getting the geometric sum until (n-1), why are you writing the formula as if we are going all the way until n? Shouldn't it be 5 * (1-2^(n-1))/(1-2)

Comment: Your first equation indicates you're getting the sum until n but your last term is n-1

Comment: Notice that there are $n$ terms in the sum $5 + 5(2) + 5(3) + \cdots + 5(2^{n - 1})$.  The last term has exponent $n - 1$ since the formula for $a_k$ is $a_k = a_1r^{k - 1}$, so when we substitute $n$ for $k$, we obtain $a_1r^{n - 1}$. Our formula for $$S = \sum_{k = 1} a_1r^{k - 1} = a_1 + a_1r + a_1r^n + \cdots + a_1r^{n - 1}$$ is $$S = a_1\frac{1 - r^n}{1 - r}$$  Please compare equations 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $r\neq 1$, we have

$$1+r+...+r^{n-1}=\frac{(1+r+...+r^{n-1})(1-r)}{(1-r)}=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}=\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}.$$
Yours is the case $r=2$. Convince yourself of the second equality by distributing and cancelling intermediate terms. The final equality is just multiplying top and bottom by $-1$.